# Unable to generate any rpm with rpmbuild -ba option

Tags: rpmbuild

I have updated my spec file with

Source0:  myagent.tar.gz

%prep
%setup -q
%build

I have redhart-rpm-config installed.

in my script that calls the RPMbuild command I have
created the tar.gz and placed it in rpmbuild/SOURCES dir ..
I have all my binaries in there as well..

Then I call the rpmbuild -ba myspec

WHat is it that I am missing? I am using Centos 6.4 with kernel 2.6.32-504

I do not see my rpms generated.

Comment: seems like my spec file version is the problem...

Comment: Can someone good at string editor help me with this ?

Comment: Can someone good at string editor help me with this ? sed "s/\(Release:\s*\)1\(%{?dist}\)/\1$BUILD_NUMBER\2/" <$HOME/agent.spec > agent_$VERSION-tmp.spec sed "S/1.0.0./${RPM_VERSION}/" < agent_$VERSION-tmp.spec > agent_$VERSION-tmp2.spec  sed "s/SUPLIST=\"\"/SUPLIST=\"${SUPLIST}\"/" < agent_$VERSION-tmp2.spec > agent_$VERSION.spec